# Reduce Margin Around Chart

Tags: html, css, charts

I have used the Plotalot extension to create different types of charts on my Joomla site. I am having issues with the margin around the piece charts in particular. I have placed the chart inside a container and although I have made the chart almost the full size of the container it leaves massive margins around the sides and bottom. I'm not quite sure how to reduce this white area around it.

Here is the CSS that I have so far for both the container and the chart itself:

```
#chart_42_container   {
clear: right;
float: right;
margin-left: 1px;
 width: 577px;
 height: 400px;
}

#chart_42 {
 height: 398px;
 width: 575px;
}
```

Here's the HTML that I have in the article itself:

```
<div id="chart_42_container">{plotalot id="42"}
<i>If you're wondering why the total of the three groups displayed in this graphs is greater than the number of reviews we analyzed (425) for the Bissell Spotlifter 1716B, this is because there were 2 reviews that made both positive and negative remarks about this unit's suction.</i>    
</div>
```

I tried to add a comment in italics below the graph in the space below the chart using the `<em>` tags, but this has been pushed down and overlaps the text in one of the paragraphs.

Here's the section with the piece chart: https://www.reviewminr.com/product-reviews/carpet-cleaner-reviews/bissell-spotlifter-1716b-review#suction

I know it must be possible to reduce these margins somehow as on the Extension's demo site, they have two of these same pie charts with none of these big white margins and they also have the comments in italics right below the the graphs.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: In terms of specifics what is required?

Comment: Have added more details which I think should satisfy the guidelines you directed me to.

Comment: Your `#chart_42_container` element has `margin-left: 40px` set, not `1px` as your code above pretends.